# Angular how to get the attribute of a Promise<Object>?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 13 application with Oauth authentication, and I can't retrieve my session information with the loadUserProfile() function which returns a Pomise

I have to have the username information in my menu I have not arrived if I convert to json I have an out of memory because it changes my profile to infinity.

```html
{{name | async}}
```

```js
get name() {
 
    return this.oauthService.loadUserProfile();
}
```

Comment: your getter creates a new instance of http request on every change detection, that is why it doesn't work. try `name = this.oauthService.loadUserProfile(`

Comment: same problem and I can't access attributes

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use a local variable for the `userProfile` after it loaded?

```
this.oauthService.loadUserProfile().then((value) => {
  this.name = value
  // Trigger cdr.markForCheck() if needed
})
```

Then use `name` on your template

But i wonder why `this.oauthService.loadUserProfile()` return a promise instead of an observable?, if it return an observable as default in http request, you can use `{{ name | async }}` easily in your template

Comment: i use lib angular-oauth2-oidc who return promise

Comment: then you can try my solution? work for you?

Comment: yes but values it's some time not load

Comment: I guess it's because your component is using `OnPush` strategy. In that case, you must inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and trigger `.markForCheck()`